# Parsing file name and return subtring

Tags: c#

I need get "PR" string from string mask without regular expression "TEST_FILE_042014_PR_001". PR element always before _001.
    How the best way?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here.

Comment: `string result = "PR";` is the best way to get "PR" string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
yourString.Split('_')[3]
```

Comment: This relies on a fixed number of underscores, though. The OP was not exactly clear on this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way

```
string str = "TEST_FILE_042014_PR_001";
string result = str.Substring(str.IndexOf("_001") - 2, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
        string t = "TEST_FILE_042014_PR_001";
        if (t.IndexOf("PR") != -1)
        {
            string last = t.Substring((int)t.IndexOf("PR") + 2) ;
            string first = t.Substring(0, (int)t.IndexOf("PR"));
            string mid = t.Substring((int)t.IndexOf("PR"),2);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] parts = yourString.Split('_');
int l = parts.Length;
if (l >=2 ) return  parts[l - 2];
```